# Как записать этот код элегантнее?

Tags: python, инспекция-кода, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.title("Нумерация")

flats = []
flats1 = []
flats2 = []
flats3 = []



def addFlat():


    kom_kv=Label(root,text='Введите номер квартиры с несколькими собственниками:')
    kom_kv.grid()
    kom_kv1=Entry(root)
    kom_kv1.grid()
    sobs=Label(root,text='Введите колличество собственников:')
    sobs.grid()
    sobs1=Entry(root)
    sobs1.grid()

    flats.append(kom_kv)
    flats1.append(kom_kv1)
    flats2.append(sobs)
    flats3.append(sobs1)

def deleteFlat():
    if flats!=0 and flats1!=0 and flats2!=0 and flats!=0: 
        flats.pop().grid_forget()
        flats1.pop().grid_forget()
        flats2.pop().grid_forget()
        flats3.pop().grid_forget()

plus=Button(root,text='Добавить квартиру', command=addFlat)
plus.grid()

plus2=Button(root,text='Удалить квартиру', command=deleteFlat)
plus2.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: пробелы убрать)

Comment: Обязательно опишите реализуемую функциональность и назначение кода. Подробная инструкция есть в полном описании метки [инспекция-кода].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 1. Один список вместо четырех

Вместо параллельных списков используем один список из объектов. Условно это можно представить как таблицу с несколькими строками. Каждая строка может быть представлена как: кортеж (`tuple`), список, словарь (`dict`), `namedtuple`, объект своего класса, [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) (Python 3.7 и новее).

Преимущество списка перед своим контейнерным типом (вариант @RafaelOsipov): не нужно самому реализовывать <s>велосипед</s> все свойства и методы, которые могут пригодиться, а просто используем уже готовый встроенный тип, который все умеет, и может хранить все что в него положишь.

Теперь по поводу типов данных, которые мы можем использовать для хранения "строк" таблицы внутри списка:

- Минус кортежей и списков: поля кортежа и элементы списка не имеют
  имен, можно что-то случайно перепутать, если записать не в том
  порядке.
- Минус словаря: в словаре может быть больше полей или меньше чем
  нужно, у полей нет определенного порядка.
- Минус `namedtuple`: `namedtuple` (кортеж с именованными полями) - это
  неизменяемый тип (как и обычный кортеж), т.е. значения в нем нельзя
  изменить, только создать новый другой кортеж с другими значениями. Но
  если значения в строке таблицы не планируется изменять, то это вполне
  рабочий вариант.
- Минус своего класса: нужно полностью описывать поведение класса
  (например, инициализацию значений, строковое представление, методы
  сравнения на равенство или порядок). `dataclass` в этом плане удобнее - просто описываются поля класса, а большая часть полезных методов генерируется автоматически.
- Вариант с `dataclass` всем прекрасен, но лично я пока не перешел на
  Python 3.7 :)
- Кстати да, можно сгруппировать элементы управления в фрейм и хранить в списке фреймы. Но это сделает более сложным процесс извлечения данных из элементов управления, например, если вы захотите сохранить данные в файл.

Пример с кортежем:

```
flats = []

def addFlat():
    ...

    flats.append((kom_kv, kom_kv1, sobs, sobs1))

def deleteFlat():
    if flats:
        kom_kv, kom_kv1, sobs, sobs1 = flats.pop()
        kom_kv.destroy()
        kom_kv1.destroy()
        sobs.destroy()
        sobs1.destroy()
```

*Элементы управления в tkinter лучше удалять с помощью `destroy`, а не с помощью `grid_forget`, если вы не собираетесь потом возвращать их обратно. Все элементы управления "удаленные" через `grid_forget` остаются висеть в памяти до закрытия программы.*

## 2. Отделение данных от графического интерфейса

У вас данные хранятся прямо в окне. Желательно так не делать, а хранить данные во внутреннем представлении, а уже при необходимости их вывода создавать элементы управления. В качестве бонуса у вас не будет такой жесткой привязки к тому же tkinter. А внутреннее представление можно уже будет перевести в любое внешнее представление: с помощью другой библиотеки GUI, на консоли, в файле, в базе данных.

## 3. Таблица для отображения данных вместо кучи текстовых полей

Можно оставить фиксированное количество текстовых полей (2 в вашем случае) для ввода данных и таблицу для отображения данных.

Представьте, что вы вводите данные о многоквартирном доме: всего лишь 5 подъездов по 5 этажей по 4 квартиры на лестничной площадке и по 4 элемента управления = 400 элементов управления уезжают далеко вниз за границы экрана. Можно прикрутить полосу прокрутки, но это будет довольно костыльно.

Минимальный пример с таблицей:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root=Tk()
root.title("Нумерация")


def addFlat():
    flat_number = entry_flat_number.get()
    owner_number = entry_owner_number.get()
    table.insert('', 'end', values=(flat_number, owner_number))

def deleteFlat():
    selected = table.selection()
    if selected:
        table.delete(selected)

Label(root,text = 'Введите номер квартиры с несколькими собственниками:').grid()
entry_flat_number = Entry(root)
entry_flat_number.grid(row=0, column=1)
Label(root,text='Введите количество собственников:').grid()
entry_owner_number = Entry(root)
entry_owner_number.grid(row=1, column=1)

Button(root,text='Добавить квартиру', command=addFlat).grid()
Button(root,text='Удалить выбранные квартиры', command=deleteFlat).grid(row=2, column=1)

table = ttk.Treeview(root)
table.grid(columnspan=2, sticky='nswe')
table['columns'] = ['flat_number', 'owner_number']
table.column('#0', width=0)

table.heading('#1', text='Номер квартиры')
table.heading('#2', text='Количество собственников')

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 5):

Вместо того, чтобы держать несколько параллельно обрабатываемых массивов, сделайте класс `Flat`, в котором будут поля:

- Номер квартиры
- Количество собственников

Затем сделайте класс `FlatCollection`, внутри которого и будет массив объектов класса `Flat` и у которого будут методы `addFlat` и `deleteFlat`

Затем создавайте экземпляр класса `FlatCollection` и добавляйте/удаляйте объекты класса `Flat` в него.

Так будет намного элегантнее.

**Небольшое дополнение:**
Согласно [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) методы классов в пайтоне принято именовать не в [camelCase](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) а в [snakeCase](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case). То есть вместо `addFlat` и `deleteFlat` принято называть методы `add_flat` и `delete_flat`.

Comment: можно рациональнее записать этот код， не используя ооп?

Comment: Ну как вам сказать. В принципе, если ООП применять нельзя, у вас более-менее оптимальная реализация. Единственное что - причешите форматирование и именование методов (snake_case). Используйте [PyCharm Community Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download). Он бесплатный и в нём есть весь необходимый инструментарий для вас.